# Why do generics often use T?

Tags: generics, naming-conventions

Is there any reason for the use of 'T' in generics? Is it some kind of abbreviation? As far as I know, everything works. For example

```
public G Say<G>(){ ... }
```

or even

```
public Hello Say<Hello>(){ ... }
```

Comment: Asked here [what-does-t-mean-in-c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400314/what-does-t-mean-in-c?lq=1) too.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

T is for **T**ype. But it's really just a tradition and there is nothing to prevent you from using other names. For example, generic dictionaries use `<TKey, TValue>`.

There is also a [Microsoft guideline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/lv-lv/library/ms229040(en-us).aspx) that recommends using the letter **T** if you have a single type parameter, and prefix descriptive parameter names with **T** if you have more than one. Doing so will provide a more consistent feel across your code.

Answer (score 8):

T for Type,
as like you said everything works fine.But putting T in that place remind you that is of generic type.

Answer (score 7):

It's just a shorthand like I is conventionally used for interfaces in .NET, and in other environments C is sometimes used for classes (Delphi uses this, IIRC).

Generally "T" on its own means "the single type parameter in this context" and if you have multiple type parameters, they get a T prefix, e.g. `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. It just makes it obvious when you're reading the code that it's a type parameter rather than a specific concrete type.

Answer (score 5):

oh, I would have thought T for Thing :)

Comment: I though it was T for "This totally rocks!"

Comment: I thought it was T for 2 at 4.

Answer (score 2):

There might also be a bit of tradition too as C++ templates use T most of the time, and generics are similar in function to C++'s templates, when used for generic programming.

Answer (score 1):

> *T for Type*

Also, E is used for Element that's very common too. You're right G also works.

Answer (score 1):

If your generic type represents something special, you can make it more precise.. Usually prefixing it with T : `IRepository<TEntity>, SomeCollection<TItem, TComparer>` ..

Answer (score 0):

I thought that was T for Template because it first appears in C++.