# What does "T" mean in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a VB background and I'm converting to C# for my new job.  I'm also trying to get better at .NET in general.  I've seen the keyword "T" used a lot in samples people post.  What does the "T" mean in C#?  For example:

```
public class SomeBase<T> where T : SomeBase<T>, new()
```

What does `T` do? Why would I want to use it?

Comment: T ~>> type : any type you want

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's a symbol for a [generic type parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx). It could just as well be something else, for example:

```
public class SomeBase<GenericThingy> where GenericThingy : SomeBase<GenericThingy>, new()
```

Only T is the default one used and encouraged by Microsoft.

Answer (score 49):

T is not a keyword per-se but a placeholder for a generic type.  See Microsoft's [Introduction to Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(vs.80).aspx)

The equivalent VB.Net syntax would be:

```
Public Class SomeBase(Of T As {Class, New}))
```

Answer (score 17):

A good example of another name used instead of T `would` be the hash table classes, e.g.

```
public class Dictionary<K,V> ...
```

Where `K` stands for Key and `V` for value. I think `T` stands for type.

You might have seen this around. If you can make the connection, it should be fairly helpful.

Answer (score 6):

That would be a "Generic". As people have already mentioned, there is a [Microsoft explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(vs.80).aspx) of the concept. As for why the "T" - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374014/why-do-generics-often-use-t).

In a nutshell, it allows you to create a class/method which is specialized to a specific type. A classical example is the `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` class. It's the same as `System.Collections.ArrayList`, except that it allows you to store only item of type `T`. This provides type safety - you can't (accidentally or otherwise) put items of the wrong type in your list. The `System.Collections.Generic` namespace contains several other different collection types which make use of this.

As for where you could use it - that's up to you. There are many use-cases which come up from time to time. Mostly it's some kind of a self-made collection (when the builtin ones don't suffice), but it could really be anything.

Answer (score 5):

Best way would be to get yourself familiar with "Generics", many resources on the web, here's [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(vs.80).aspx)

T is not a keyword but a name, could be anything really as far as I know, but T is the convention (when only one type is needed, of coruse)

Answer (score 3):

The `T` is the name for the type parameter in a generic class. It stands for "Type" but you could just as well call it "Alice."

You use generics to increase reusability in a type-safe manner without needlessly duplicating code. Thus, you do not need to write classes for `ListOfIntegers`, `ListOfStrings`, `ListOfChars`, `ListOfPersons` and so on but can instead write a generic class `List<T>` and then instantiate objects of types `List<Int32>`, `List<string>`, `List<char>` and `List<Person>`. The compiler does the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

It means "any class". It could be "B", "A", whatever. I think T is used because of "Template"

Comment: Type would be more appropriate than class in this context as T can be both a reference and a value type.

Comment: I believe that the "Template" terminology comes from C++ templates.  The single-letter capitalized parameter smells like C++ macros.

Comment: T is definitely favored for the same role in C++ templates (but there it is still short for "Type" -- it's taking the place of a Type, not a Template)