# Class syntax with <TypeParameter> C#

Tags: c#, .net, class, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “T” mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400314/what-does-t-mean-in-c)
>   [What does <T> denote in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857180/what-does-t-denote-in-c-sharp)

I have searched about the question, but because I do not have any idea about that syntax, I could not search well enough. Well, after the short explanation my question is :

While I was looking to a particle effect library I meet this :

```cs
[Serializable]
public class DPSF<Particle, Vertex> : IDPSFParticleSystem
  where Particle : global::DPSF.DPSFParticle, new()
  where Vertex : struct, global::DPSF.IDPSFParticleVertex
{
  // constructors, methods, parameters here ...
}
```

What does this notation mean in blankets (<...>) and how it is used ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "T" mean in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400314/what-does-t-mean-in-c) and [What does <T> denote in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857180/what-does-t-denote-in-c-sharp)

Comment: thanks ! I'm reading the post and i'm curious why there is "where Particle : ... " is it a restriction ? I know what T means, but I have never seen it using with a class ! I know using T at function, but still I want to learn its concept using at classes

Comment: @icaptan yes, they're formally called constraints.  There is a section describing them in the article linked to by BlueRaja

Comment: [The section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28VS.80%29.aspx#csharp_generics_topic4) mentioned by @heavyd

Answer (score 2):

They are generic types that you can pass into a class definition:

A simple example:

```
public class Test<T>
{
   public T yourVariable;  
}

Test<int> intClass = new Test();
Test<string> stringClass = new Test();

intClass.yourVariable // would be of type int
stringClass.yourVariable // would be of type string
```

Where T is the type you want (i.e. another class, a string, integer, anything generic)

where Particle : global::DPSF.DPSFParticle - means that the Particle object must inherit from DPSF.DPSFParticle

Comment: and what about the where clouse ? is it a restriction ?

Comment: Must inherit from DPSF.DPSFParticle.

Comment: Thanks i understood the answer well ! thank you all very much !

Answer (score 1):

It means that DPSF class is a generic class. Particle and Vertex between <> are type parameters. It means that DPSF gets two types as parameters and serves as a generic class.

Take a look at here: [MSDN: Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

**EDIT**
Where keyword allows you to restrict type parameters. where:class means parameter must be a class in order this generic class to work.