# Why the datatype for generics is denoted by <T>

Tags: generics

This is one of my interview question.

Why the datatype is denoted by the letter  in generics and why not some other letter/alphabet.

Comment: The T is for Type.

Comment: T is a user-defined name in the languages I know... it could just as well be `Type` or `Whatever_the_programmer_wanted_to_call_it`. For example, in the D standard library, it is often `Range` because these functions accept a generic range type instead of just anything.

Comment: A [quick search of SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=generic+letter+t) turns up [Why do generics often use T?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374014/why-do-generics-often-use-t) as the #1 hit.

Comment: Basically just repeating what the comments to the question already said:
T is commonly used because it means Type, but all programming languages I know of allow you to specify your own names for generic type parameters, just like you can with variables, class names, method/function names, etc.